# I'm trying to replace the colons and spaces with commas in Processing

Tags: java, processing, replaceall

I'm pretty new to Processing and Java so this is probably pretty simple. Just bear with me. It's just sliding over my head. This is the code I have

The txt file I'm pulling from consists of numbers like this:

1: 100

2: 200

3: 300 etc.

```
void setup() {

  size(200,200);

  String[] lines = loadStrings("WordFrequency.txt");

  lines = lines.replaceAll(":", ",");     
  lines = lines.replaceAll(" ", ",");     

  }

}
```

Comment: `replaceAll(":", " ")` replaces all colons with spaces. Change it to `replaceAll(":", ",").replaceAll(" ", ",")` to replace colons to commas and then spaces to commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Kevin's answer for replacing new line character. `replace` will not work because you have already parsed the new line characters while parsing the file into an array of strings.

You should append the strings after replace. Something like this:

```
String fileString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
   lines[i] = lines[i].replace(":", ",");
   lines[i] = lines[i].replace(" ", ",");
   fileString += lines[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to call `replaceAll()` on the array, which won't work. You have to iterate through the array and call it for every index. Also note that `replaceAll()` uses regular expressions, which is overkill for your purposes. I'd use `replace()` instead. More info can be found in [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

So, what you're describing is three steps:

**Step 1:** Loop through every `String` in your array.

**Step 2:** Replace the colons with commas.

**Step 3:** Replace the spaces with commas.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
   lines[i] = lines[i].replace(":", ",");
   lines[i] = lines[i].replace(" ", ",");
}
```

You could shorten that to call `replace()` directly on the value returned from the first call to `replace()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
   lines[i] = lines[i].replace(":", ",").replace(" ", ",");
}
```

But this code isn't faster than the first option, so really you should stick with whatever code you understand the best.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm trying to replace a new line with a "," but 

    lines[j] = lines[j].replace("\n", "");

will not work.

Comment: @CanoBriseno The `loadStrings()` function already removes new line characters- that's how it knows where each index should end. What exactly are you trying to do?